# Transplanting/mailing a fern

Tags: transplanting, ferns

I have a lot of ferns growing in my garden in the UK. I would like to send one to a friend who has moved away (also in the UK), as it's their favourite plant.

I believe ours are mostly "[Male Fern](https://www.woodlandtrust.org.uk/trees-woods-and-wildlife/plants/ferns/scaly-male-fern/)" at this time of year they are still in  full leaf.

What would be the best process to dig up a plant and package it so it has a good chance to regrow? Should leaves be removed, should I maybe pot one and wait for it to die back in winter first? Since I'll need to post it, reducing the size/weight as far as practicable would be good.

Will this plant grow inside, or in a pot outside?

Comment: Pots outdoors would work. Remove most soil and wrap in wet newspaper or rags to ship, but not by air. Send some that way. Cut 2/3 of the roots on others, along with 2/3 of the foliage to offset the shock. All should then grow back.

Comment: @Mr.Boy Where in the world does your friend live?

Comment: @MackM thanks - still UK so climate the same

Answer (score 2):

I have never shipped any live plant, so I can only offer what I read online.

The folks of [Fancy Fronds Nursery](https://www.fancyfrondsnursery.com/faqmain) in Washington, USA sell ferns through the mail.  This is what their FAQ says about their shipping:

> We only ship via United States Postal
> Service Priority Mail to ensure your plants do not spend long in
> transit.  Delivery typically takes 1-3 days from the ship date
> depending on your location.  Plants and are removed from their
> containers and put into plastic sleeves to help them retain moisture
> on their journey and protect their fronds.  The root-ball and fronds
> are then carefully wrapped in newsprint to cushion them and protect
> the fronds from breaking.  Plants are packed tightly in a box so they
> cannot shift and break during transit.  We take great care not to
> stack our plants so deep that they get crushed from the weight, which
> means you may receive several small to medium sized boxes instead of
> one large one.  All plants are shipped with their name label which
> includes information on plant size, common name, and preferred growing
> conditions.  We do not bare-root our plants and make every effort to
> have them arrive with their fronds intact.

Elsewhere on their site they say that they do not air-mail, and they do not mail during seasons with harsh weather. This all matches the plant shipping advice I see elsewhere, other than not bare-rooting the plants.

I don't know if pruning or waiting for a winter die back will stop it from regrowing. My hunch is no, but if the weather is harsh enough to cause it to die back, I wouldn't want to ship it in that weather anyway.